# open big URL from a batch file

Tags: web-services, batch-file

I had tried many examples from the search, but still not finding any closer to my scenario. We want to open a URL in IE, which actually is a web service call and sends SMS. Below code is tried;

```
@START http://172.20.10.1/smsservice/smsservice.asmx/SMSPush?ApplicationID=username&Password=password&MobileNumber="12345678"&MessageText="Test SMS"&ConfirmDelivery=False&Priority=0
```

However, IE only opens shorten URL with

`"http://172.20.10.1/smsservice/smsservice.asmx/SMSPush?ApplicationID=username"`.

It doesn't go beyond & sign.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `@START "" http://172.20.10.1/smsservice/smsservice.asmx/SMSPush?ApplicationID=username^&Password=password^&MobileNumber="12345678"^&MessageText="Test SMS"^&ConfirmDelivery=False^&Priority=0` and escape each `&` as `^&` instead.

Comment: @Rock have you had the chance to try the solutions?

Comment: Hello Maytham, Thanks for reaching out :) Yes, indeed the generosity of members such as yours helped me in achieving the desired outcome in no-time :) :) Thanks for all the speedy help..Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

use quotes

```
@START "" "http://173.20.10.1/smsservice/smsservice.asmx/SMSPush?ApplicationID=username&Password=password&MobileNumber="12345678"&MessageText="Test%%20SMS"&ConfirmDelivery=False&Priority=0"
```

Comment: I have tested this and the url ends till the space that comes after "Test

Comment: I fixed it an include encoding for the space (%20)

Comment: Thank you very much, your provided suggestion works absolutely fine. Kudos to you :)

Answer (score 1):

This would work

```
@START /d "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" IEXPLORE.EXE "http://172.20.10.1/smsservice/smsservice.asmx/SMSPush?ApplicationID=username&Password=password&MobileNumber="12345678"&MessageText="Test SMS"&ConfirmDelivery=False&Priority=0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape each `&` as `^&` instead and use the first set of double quotes after [START](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command for blank title.

```
@START "" http://172.20.10.1/smsservice/smsservice.asmx/SMSPush?Applic‌​ationID=username^&Pa‌​ssword=password^&Mob‌​ileNumber="12345678"‌​^&MessageText="Test SMS"^&ConfirmDelivery=False^&Priority=0
```

This way you can use no double quotes just as you are around the URL string but tell the batch to interpret `&` symbol as that character literally rather than [conditional logic](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html).

Answer (score 0):

The quotes in the middle of the url have to be escaped with a backslash.

```
@START "" "http://173.20.10.1/smsservice/smsservice.asmx/SMSPush?ApplicationID=username&Password=password&MobileNumber=\"12345678\"&MessageText=\"Test SMS\"&ConfirmDelivery=False&Priority=0"
```